# Define polygon with even number of points?

Tags: polygon, point

I have the following problem.....  I have a client that needs an equal number of schools divided up between 8 different zones.

The state I am looking at is the state of Maryland.  They want to use the zip code that each school is in instead of the actual location of the school.

So, for example, ZIP 21050 might have 13 schools, 20601 has 5, 20618 has 15, 20623 has 9, etc etc etc....

How can I break up the state into 8 overall zones, and with each zone having an equal (or close to equal) number of schools?  The zones will be bound by zip code boundaries.

The purpose is for some kind of inspections I believe and they want each of the 8 inspection teams to have roughly the same number of schools to cover....

Any advice?

Comment: Look for redistricting software which should be able to handle this easily

Comment: Some basic statistics would be useful - a quick search tells me there's 603 zip codes in Maryland and 1424 public schools. [http://maryland.educationbug.org/public-schools/] - is that about the scale of the problem? Any chance of access to the data - ie a zip code map with number of schools?

Comment: The Maryland GIS Data Catalog has data for anyone wanting to try this problem: http://data.imap.maryland.gov/datasets/maryland-education-facilities-k-thru-12-education-public-schools/data

Comment: I assume you want contiguous and compact areas - otherwise dividing the state into approximately 1/8 (by total school number) horizontal, vertical, or diagonal strips will satisfy your requirements.